# orientdb cluster / console

Tags: console, cluster-computing, orientdb

I have installed orientdb with docker.
All objects appear normal in the studio interface. But I can't list the clusters correctly. Only the id appears:

```
orientdb {db=GratefulDeadConcerts}> list clusters                                     


CLUSTERS (collections)
+----+-----+-----+
|#   |NAME |COUNT|
+----+-----+-----+
|0   |     |     |
|1   |     |     |
|2   |     |     |
|3   |     |     |
|4   |     |     |
|5   |     |     |
|6   |     |     |
|7   |     |     |
|8   |     |     |
|9   |     |     |
|10  |     |     |
|11  |     |     |
|12  |     |     |
|13  |     |     |
|14  |     |     |
|15  |     |     |
|16  |     |     |
|17  |     |     |
|18  |     |     |
|19  |     |     |
|20  |     |     |
|21  |     |     |
|22  |     |     |
|23  |     |     |
|24  |     |     |
|25  |     |     |
|26  |     |     |
|27  |     |     |
|28  |     |     |
|29  |     |     |
|30  |     |     |
|31  |     |     |
|32  |     |     |
|33  |     |     |
|34  |     |     |
|35  |     |     |
|36  |     |     |
|37  |     |     |
|38  |     |     |
|39  |     |     |
|40  |     |     |
|41  |     |     |
|42  |     |     |
|43  |     |     |
|44  |     |     |
|45  |     |     |
|46  |     |     |
|47  |     |     |
|48  |     |     |
|49  |     |     |
|50  |     |     |
|51  |     |     |
|52  |     |     |
+----+-----+-----+
|    |TOTAL|    0|
+----+-----+-----+
```

Cluster names appear correctly on the Studio interface

Why is there a difference between the console and the interface/studio ?

Comment: which version of orient are you using?